# How to show error once range is already exists?

Tags: java

I have below code

```
    HashMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> allData = new HashMap<>();
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(1.00),new BigDecimal(100.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(101.00),new BigDecimal(200.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(201.00),new BigDecimal(300.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(111.00),new BigDecimal(150.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(301.00),new BigDecimal(400.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(401.00),new BigDecimal(500.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(210.00),new BigDecimal(220.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(501.00),new BigDecimal(600.00));
```

Here

```
 allData.put(new BigDecimal(111.00),new BigDecimal(150.00));
 allData.put(new BigDecimal(210.00),new BigDecimal(220.00));
```

If user enters all data, then above 2 ones will be invalid, because that range is already exists.

How to check?

Comment: [HashMap.containsKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Hi @David I need to check range in between.

Comment: That's not a range. That's a key->value hash map. I suppose you *could* use it for that purpose, but it's very counterintuitive as you need to know the value of the minimum to find the maximum.

Comment: One solution that comes to mind with this unorthodox method would be to get the list of keys in the map, iterate through them, using each key to find the respective value, and then check if the input key and value from the user lies between the minimum and maximum value on each iteration.

Comment: Do you mean if a new entry overlaps with any existing entry or only if it is the exact same range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HashMap` to store the ranges for your use-case seems not to be the ideal way.

In your implementation, if a new range has the same lower bound as an already existing range, it would overwrite the existing entry.

The output of the following example

```java
HashMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> allData = new HashMap<>();
allData.put(new BigDecimal(1.00),new BigDecimal(100.00));
allData.put(new BigDecimal(1.00),new BigDecimal(200.00));

System.out.println(allData);
```

is `{1=200}`.

As you can see, the second `put` overwrites the first entry.

If you want to stay with your `HashMap` implementation you can do this check, if a new entry overlaps with an existing entry, before executing the `put`:

```java
    HashMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> allData = new HashMap<>();
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(1.00),new BigDecimal(100.00));
    allData.put(new BigDecimal(101.00),new BigDecimal(200.00));

    BigDecimal lowerBound = new BigDecimal(111.00);
    BigDecimal upperBound = new BigDecimal(150.00);

    //check if lowerBound or upperBound is between any existing entry
    boolean isOverlapping = allData.entrySet().stream()
        .anyMatch(e -> (e.getKey().compareTo(lowerBound) <= 0 && e.getValue().compareTo(lowerBound) >= 0)
            || e.getKey().compareTo(upperBound) <= 0 && e.getValue().compareTo(upperBound) >= 0);

    if(isOverlapping) {
      System.out.println("is overlapping");
    } else {
      allData.put(lowerBound, upperBound);
    }
```

---

**Alternative Approach, using custom class**

Better use a custom class for your ranges, which implements a method, that checks if one range is overlapping with another. It could look like this:

```java
public class Range {
  private BigDecimal lowerBound;
  private BigDecimal upperBound;

  public Range(BigDecimal lowerBound, BigDecimal upperBound) {
    this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
  }

  public BigDecimal getLowerBound() {
    return lowerBound;
  }

  public BigDecimal getUpperBound() {
    return upperBound;
  }


  public boolean overlapsWith(Range other) {
    return (lowerBound.compareTo(other.lowerBound) >= 0 && upperBound.compareTo(other.lowerBound) <= 0)
        || (lowerBound.compareTo(other.upperBound) >= 0 && upperBound.compareTo(other.upperBound) <= 0);
  }
}
```

When using a `List` to store your range-values you can simply use the `anyMatch` method to check if there is an overlapping range, like in the following example:

```java
    List<Range> allData = new ArrayList<>();
    allData.add(new Range(new BigDecimal(111.00), new BigDecimal(150.00)));

    Range anotherRange = new Range(new BigDecimal(111.00), new BigDecimal(150.00));

    boolean isOverlapping = allData.stream().anyMatch(range -> range.overlapsWith(anotherRange));

    if(isOverlapping) {
      System.out.println("already exists");
    } else {
      allData.add(anotherRange);
      System.out.println("added");
    }
```

Comment: Can I define lower & upper bound to max? Because we can't define. We need to take from the data which users provide.

Answer (score 0):

If the map is not too big, you can scan through the whole map for an existing range using something like

```
allData().entrySet().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getKey().compareTo(lower) <= 0 && e.getValue().compareTo(upper) >= 0)`
```

where `lower` and `upper` are the bounds of the range to be added.

Comment: At this solution, only if any of the existing ranges fully includes the new range would deliver `true`. The case when only the lower or the upper bound is included will not be considered.

Comment: Correct, this only checks for containment, not for non-empty intersection. From the OP it was not clear to me whether we should also check for non-empty intersection. So I decided to keep things short. Adjusting the lambda should be easy, I hope.